# How to do two different compilations in the same MSI (visual studio 2022)?

Tags: visual-c++

I have an application which I can compile for cmd and with a graphical interface. To chose the target I use a #define (not the most beautiful solution, but it works) to chose the output. Its deliver it via a set up project in Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project 2022, that works fine..

BUT now I want both versions to be delivered in the same MSI; both the cmd version and the graphical! What I can do is to first compile the cmd-version and then take the exe file and include it in the Installer Project as a file, and then compile it again with the graphical interface and generate a MDI-file. but that is a two step process and not error prone.
Can I include both in the same build? ...then HOW?

The application is written in C++ if that matters...

I want want something like four targets "Release cmd", "Release Win", "Debug cmd" and "Debug Win" targets

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. But, you can set your two different "Release" builds to have different output directories, then include the two (different) executables in the MSI. But you would also need to ensure that they either have different names or different target locations (like two different subfolders of the selected installation location).